# PHP - SQL not returning row but works on local server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to get a row, But it does not return anything on my site, But it works perfectly on local host.

```
public function GetVote($rel)
    {
        include 'config.php';

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT updown FROM user_votes WHERE UID = :id AND rel = :rel");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $this->id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":rel", $rel);
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $row['updown'];
    }
```

Running SQL on phpmyadmin, Site:
[image]

Running SQL on phpmyadmin, Local:

[image]

- I dont know why its saying there is no unique colum, VID is unique and auto-increment.

Table structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an Image of your Table Structure of your Server DB?

Comment: `VID` is unique, but you are only `SELECT`ing the `updown` field... Therefore, you cannot edit the data being returned.

Comment: could you try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 (or viceversa in your PHP script)? I had a similar problem, and traced it back to the mysqli_connect..., 127.0.0.1 was failing (no data was returned as script could not even connect to DB) but localhost was ok.

Comment: what type of you UID column ?

Comment: try using select * from user_votes

Comment: Try to execute Select Query with all fields like @chiragode suggested and then try to print `print_r($row);`

Comment: @AaronGong Local host is working fine, Its my host server thats the problem.

Comment: And if you're getting any error after doing above then also add that error in your question.

Comment: @chiragode Still returns nothing.

Comment: @NullVoid There is no error, Just returns nothing.

Comment: have you used print_r($row);as @NullVoid suggested...then tell whats the error

Comment: hi, are you able to even connect to the DB via your own PHP script? If yes, then can proceed to troubleshooting the no results issue.

Comment: @AaronGong Yes, its connecting fine, the rest of the site has no issues.

Comment: @chiragode Yes ive tried that, Always empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VID` is unique, but your are only `SELECT`ing the `updown` field. Therefore, phpMyAdmin can't let you edit the data and it produces that warning.

Also, try following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user_votes`
WHERE `UID`='76561197996836099'
AND `rel`='5'
LIMIT 0,30
```

I've noticed the `UID` and `ref` fields are varchar, but you're sending an integer (way to big, btw)...

Comment: Its varchar because im using Steam 64 ID's, they sometimes start with a 0 that would be lost if it was integer, also i have a local UID that starts with "la". And ive tried * and still returns nothing. I only need updown returned on the script.

Comment: TristanCunningham, Marty has suggested correct way to compare `String` id. You were using as an Integer whereas UID is a `VARCHAR`

Comment: This looks good, even the fields are contained in (`). You can use single quotes (') for number values also.

Answer (score 1):

just try this and tell..any output or not??

```
public function GetVote($rel)
{
include 'config.php';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_votes WHERE rel = :rel");

$stmt->bindParam(":rel", $rel);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $row['updown'];
}
```

Comment: That returns the rows.

Comment: Yeah, Its been fixed now. There was a confict with the UID veriable somewhere else that was causing this.